# how to do a dynamic function calls (HOFs)

Tags: xslt, xslt-3.0

Consider

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:kooks="kookerella.com"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:function name="kooks:one" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:sequence select="1"/>
    </xsl:function>
    
    <xsl:function name="kooks:two" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:sequence select="2"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="two" select="kooks:two()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="two_func" select="kooks:two"/>
        <xsl:variable name="two_2" select="$two_func()"/>
        <root>
            <xsl:sequence select="$two_2"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this fails (in saxon) with

```
The only value that can pass type-checking is an empty sequence.
The required item type of the target of the dynamic function call 
is function(*), but the supplied expression {$two_func} has item 
type element(Q{kookerella.com}two)
```

how do i call functions dynamically?

(basically how do I do higher order functions/templates in XSLT 2.0/3.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:kooks="kookerella.com"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:function name="kooks:one" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:sequence select="1"/>
    </xsl:function>
    
    <xsl:function name="kooks:two" as="xs:integer">
        <xsl:sequence select="2"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="two" select="kooks:two()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="two_func" select="kooks:two#0"/>
        <xsl:variable name="two_2" select="$two_func()"/>
        <root>
            <xsl:sequence select="$two_2"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The relevant XPath 3.1 grammar section: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-named-function-ref.

Comment: ah...ok...so I'm selecting specifically a the function "kooks:two" with 0 params? (i.e. it supports function overloading by number of params?

Comment: Yes, you have to give the name and the arity of the function.